# angularjs multiselect dropdown makes page heavy due to document's click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have implemented this angular multiselect dropdown.
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

It has below method which keeps tracking event to close dropdowns which are open.

```
 if ($scope.settings.closeOnBlur) {
     $document.on('click', function (e) {
             // some code here
     });
 }
```

You can find this method at 
https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js

This method makes my angularJS page heavy which inturn deteriotes performance.

What's can be done as an alternative ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code?  function where ? In the view? Digests can run multiple times if that is the case and using functions in view can actually increase it

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I found the problem now. I am updating the question.

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've added an optimization to the template generation in the multi-select module so that the dropdown is lazy-generated, reducing the number of watches significantly.
This should speed up your page loading and behavior on clicks events.

I submitted a [pull-request](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/pull/175), but the repository doesn't seem to be frequently maintained.
You can check-out from [here](https://github.com/odedfos/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect)

Most of the credit goes to [gilad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3285914/gilad)

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular material virtual/lazy loading feature, that way performance will be optimal.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
                    <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.filterDS" class="repeated-item-vertical" ng-click="ctrl.toggleSelection(item.name,item.id)" flex>

                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.name}}" ng-checked="item.selected">{{item.indent}} {{item.name}}

                    </div>
                </md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Refer:
http://jsfiddle.net/VBharath/n1r6hwcg/22/